# Extra indentation for private methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indentation, rubymine

Is there any way to make RubyMine put an extra indentation for `private` methods? For example:

```
def a_public_method
  # ...
end

private

  def a_private_method
    # ...
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in their feature request list ( not implemented yet)

You can vote on it here.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-8497

Comment: Wow it was created in 2011, that feature must be really down in their list of things to implement, if it is in the list at all.

Comment: when you are reading this in 2022 and you are still wondering if it is already implemented

Answer (score 0):

This has finally been implemented:

[image]